# How to customize the error message on programmatically created LongRangeValidator?

Tags: validation, jsf

I created a long range validator but I am not able to find a way to customize the corresponding message text. I am using JSF 2.x and ApacheMyFaces. Thanks in advance.

```
if ((integerField.getMaximalValue() != null) && (integerField.getMinimalValue() != null)) { // serverside validation required
    long maximum = integerField.getMaximalValue().longValue();
    long minimum = integerField.getMinimalValue().longValue();
    Validator validator = new LongRangeValidator(maximum, minimum);
    inputInteger.addValidator(validator);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`UIInput#setValidatorMessage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#setValidatorMessage%28java.lang.String%29).

```
inputInteger.setValidatorMessage("Please enter a value in range");
```